# How to test Struts2 action in Junit 4 way?

Tags: junit, struts2

There's a struts2-junit-plugin for testing Struts2 actions, but it seems to require the tests to be written in JUnit 3 style, that is I can't use @BeforeClass, @Test etc annotations and can't use BDD-style test names like "shouldDoThisAndThat()". Is there a way to combine struts2-junit-plugin and JUnit 4-style tests?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try this out:

http://glindholm.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/unit-testing-struts-2-actions/

I have found it to be very useful in testing Struts2 actions. It uses Mockrunner to simulate running in a servlet container, so you can develop your tests in any way you like, including using JUnit 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here's how I solved it, its a pretty simple base class.

In my case I use hibernate, so leave out the session/transaction stuff if you aren't using it.
This let's you keep using all the mock struts objects, which I found handy. A simple test case follows.

I still need to figure out how to inject resource bundles (i18n strings)... I will be adding that to the base class.

```
package com.accelarad.unittest;

import org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

/**
 * Bring Struts JUnit3 into the JUnit4 world
 * 
 * @author kcostilow
 *
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( { 
    "classpath:spring-datasource-unittest.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-test-hibernate.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-context.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-security.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-server.xml"
    }
)
public abstract class AbstractSpringStruts2JUnit4 extends StrutsTestCase implements ApplicationContextAware {

    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // implements ApplicationContextAware
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() {
        // in my case, I create a mock JNDI here, 
        // including a mailSession using a Wiser mock SMTP server
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp(); // use JUnit3 setUp chain. In this case setupBeforeInitDispatcher() will be called
        if (! TransactionSynchronizationManager.hasResource(sessionFactory)) {
            Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);  // first @Before only
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void setupBeforeInitDispatcher() throws Exception {
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, applicationContext);
        // inject hibernate sessionFactory into Transaction Management, simulating OpenSessionInView
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdown() {
        // in my case, I shutdown the mock mail server here
    }
}
```

Sample test case:

```
public class MyActionTest extends AbstractSpringStruts2JUnit4 {
    @Test
    public void testOneStrutsAction() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy = super.getActionProxy("/packageName/actionName");
        TestCase.assertEquals("actionName result", "success", proxy.execute());

        MyAction myAction = (MyAction ) proxy.getAction();
        TestCase.assertNotNull(myAction.getSomething());
    }
}
```

You can take it from there I think.

Comment: Re i18n: since struts files were already in my classpath, above structure was already bringing in my string properties files, so I dind't have to do anything extra for getText()s to work.

Answer (score 0):

For others who land here searching for how to test struts2 actions using Junit, here's some sample code using Struts2.3.12 & Junit 4

```
public class TestIoOptimizationAction extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase<IoOptimizationAction> {

    @Test
    public void login() throws Exception {
        request.setParameter("email", "nitin.cool4urchat@gmail.com");
        request.setParameter("password", "22");

        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("login");
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext().setSession(sessionMap);
        String result = proxy.execute();
//        String result = executeAction("/login");
        assertEquals("success", result);
        System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

I had to separately embed session map, because I'm using getActionProxy() and here's the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649952/struts2-3-12-junit4-testcase-request-session-are-null)

Answer (score 0):

Your test class should extend StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase.

Answer (score 0):

I stole a little bit from kcostilow and coding_idiot's answers and created an abstract class with `StrutsJUnit4TestCase`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( { 
    "classpath:spring-datasource-unittest.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-test-hibernate.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-context.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-security.xml", 
    "classpath:spring-server.xml"
    }
)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "dataSourceTransactionManager")
public abstract class AbstractSpringStruts2JUnit4<T extends ActionSupport> extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase<T> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource= dataSource;
    }

    @Before
    public void onSetUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setupAction();
    }

    protected abstract void setupAction();

}
```

Then extended the class to create the test:

```
public class SomeActionIntegrationTest extends AbstractSpringStruts2JUnit4<SomeAction> {
    private SomeAction someAction; // SomeAction must extend ActionSupport.

    @Override
    protected void setupAction() {
        ActionProxy proxy = super.getActionProxy("/someAction"); 
        // You might have* to add ".do" to the end of the URI. 
        So, super.getActionProxy("/someAction.do") was the only way I was able to get the proxy.

        someAction = (ActionSupport) proxy.getAction();
        assertNotNull(someAction);  
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception {
        String result = someAction.execute();
        assertEquals("input", result);
    }
}
```