# Junit testing Struts2 action with Spring

Tags: spring, struts2, junit

I want to test Struts action but I am facing the following problem:

```
SEVERE:   [09:16.218] Error building bean
```

It seems that Spring does not do dependency injection.
Indeed, if I create a default constructor I get a NPE because the service is not instantiated. My unit test extend StrutsSpringTestCase, so why my Action is not instanciate correctly ?

Here is my action :

```
public ControllerAuthentification(LdapUserService service) {
    this.ldapUserService = service;
}

public String connection() {
    if (userLdap != null) {
        ldapUserService.save(userLdap);
        addActionMessage(getText("success.connect"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return INPUT;
}
```

Unit test :

```
public class ControllerAuthentificationTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase {

    public void testConnection() throws Exception {

        request.setParameter("userLdap.login", "login");
        request.setParameter("userLdap.password", "password");
        proxy = getActionProxy("/connection");
        ControllerAuthentification action = (ControllerAuthentification) proxy.getAction();
        String result = proxy.execute();

       assertTrue("it would be true", result.equals(Action.SUCCESS));
    }
}
```

applicationContext

```
<bean id="ldapUserService" class="sword.plateformetest.service.impl.LdapUserServiceImpl" />
<bean id="ldapUserAuthAction" scope="prototype"
    class="sword.plateformetest.action.ControllerAuthentification">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapUserService" />
</bean>
```

and my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Stack trace :

```
SEVERE:   [56:08.596] Error building bean
2013-08-26 13:56:08,600 ERROR sword.plateformetest.action.ControllerAuthentificationTest.testConnection:37 - error
Unable to intantiate Action!
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:299)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.getActionProxy(StrutsTestCase.java:137)
    at sword.plateformetest.action.ControllerAuthentificationTest.testConnection(ControllerAuthentificationTest.java:34)
```

Comment: What the logs are displayed? Does it start the spring container?

Comment: I add the logs. How can I know if the spring container started ?

Comment: Should be printed in the logs.

Comment: i add the logs for org.springframework and it returned org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.prepareRefresh and org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons:555

Comment: @Guillaume did you ever get this resolved? Do you have an example of this case? I just can't get the getActionProxy() working. It throws "There is no action mapped with name" error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be extended `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase` instead. Here's my answer to it:

[How to test Struts2 action in Junit 4 way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816173/how-to-test-struts2-action-in-junit-4-way/41814091#41814091)

You might have to add the struts2-junit-plugin dependency.

As for @Kevin Rave, you might have to add ".do" to end of the URI. I was having the exact same issue and appending that resolved it.